# what is the formulas to do Fuzzy logic step by step?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

What is the formulas to do Fuzzy logic step by step?

please could someone help me learn fuzzy logic step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an [introduction to fuzzy logic](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=2184127758996040861) a while ago, it explains the basics of fuzzy logic step by step.

Comment: thanks for share!